# How can I download iCloud photos from previous/older devices?

Tags: icloud, photos

My iCloud is full and I checked what is in it. I have my current iPhone and I have two old broken iPhones and a broken iPad in there. I'm reluctant to delete them in case they have some of my much sought after photos on them. Is there any way I can access the photos and save them to my computer?

Comment: Are you saying that you have backups of those devices in iCloud? If so, no, it is not possible to retrieve anything from those backups without restoring them to a device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If on OS X, use Apple's Photos app and save the pictures locally. If on Windows, download iCloud for Windows.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Neither iCloud Photo Library nor Photo Stream differentiate photos by the device that uploaded them, so the OP stating they have their "current iPhone and...two old broken iPhones and a broken iPad in there" probably means they have device backups stored in iCloud, in which case your answer is not correct.